# Find the value of m knowing that $C(m,1)+C(m,2)+C(m,3)+....+C(m,m-1)=254$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I know that m = 8, but I solved it using brute force.
I also know that the first and the last term are the same, the second
will be the same that the last but one and ....
But now I'm stuck

Comment: Well, what is $\sum_{i=0}^n\binom ni$?  If you just work it out for small $n$, the pattern will be obvious and it is then easy to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation means that:

$$C(m,0)+C(m,1)+\cdots+C(m,m-1)+C(m,m)=1+254+1$$

And the left side is $2^m=(1+1)^m,$ by binomial theorem.

Solving $$2^m=256$$ gives $m=8.$

Comment: You added a 1 on the right side because C (m, m) was added on the left side, right?
And the second 1? where does it come from?

Comment: I added $C(m,0)$ to the left. @Gabriel

Comment: now i got it, thanks